# Picasso is not loading images into the ImageView from an URL

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, picasso

I am using Picasso to load images from a URL retrieved from an API.

This is my current Picasso configuration. I am using Dagger2 to provide Picasso dependency.

```
@Provides
Picasso getPicasso(@Named("application-context") Context context, OkHttp3Downloader downloader) {
     return new Picasso.Builder(context)
              .downloader(downloader)
              .indicatorsEnabled(true)
              .loggingEnabled(true)
              .build();
    }
```

This is my OkHttp Configuration

```
@Provides
OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor, Cache cache, Interceptor httpInterceptor) {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(httpInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .cache(cache)
            .build();
   }
```

And here is the implementation of the LoggingInterceptor

```
@Provides
HttpLoggingInterceptor getHttpLoggingInterceptor() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Timber.tag("OkHttp").d(message));         
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    return loggingInterceptor;
    }
```

But when I use picasso in the recycler view adapter like this

```
picasso.load(article.urlToImage)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .into(thumbnailImageView)
```

Only the placeholder image is being loaded. The Image Url passed isn't loading in the Image View

There are no errors thrown too.
Here is the logcat

```
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R1] Request{http://bsmedia.business-standard.com/_media/bs/img/article/2017-09/04/full/1504466214-5997.jpg}
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R0]+11ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R1]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R1]+2ms 
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R2] Request{https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-63672403,width-672,resizemode-4,imgsize-538337/air-india.jpg}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R2]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R2]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R3] Request{http://bsmedia.business-standard.com/include/_mod/site/html5/images/no-meta-preview.jpg}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R3]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R3]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R4] Request{https://www.livemint.com/rf/Image-621x414/LiveMint/Period2/2018/04/09/Photos/Processed/chaipoint-kT0--621x414@LiveMint.JPG}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R4]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R4]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R5] Request{http://bsmedia.business-standard.com/_media/bs/img/article/2018-03/12/full/1520793310-387.jpg}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R5]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R5]+1ms
```

I see that the request to load the image is being executed, but the image isn't loading.

What is the problem here?

Comment: What's your httpInterceptor doing? And any log from your loggingInterceptor?

Comment: The Http interceptor just adds some headers for the API authentication. These are the logs from the loggingInterceptor. There are no other logs in my logcat regarding picasso .

Comment: Those are logs from `loggingEnabled(true)`, you should have logs from `loggingInterceptor`, could you add this dependency code?

Comment: The only logs from the logging interceptor I see are from Retrofit. I have edited the question with the implementation of the logging interceptor.

Comment: So no logs from Timber tag `OkHttp`? You should see something like this ` * --> POST /greeting http/1.1
     * Host: example.com
     * Content-Type: plain/text
     * Content-Length: 3
     * --> END POST
     *
     * <-- 200 OK (22ms)
     * Content-Type: plain/text
     * Content-Length: 6
     * <-- END HTTP`

Comment: Yeah, I don't. I tried to debug it but in vain. I see one log from `OkHttp` tag. That log just prints out the URL of the API requested by retrofit. That's all I'm getting in the logcat

Comment: Try HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY instead of BASIC you should get more info about response code: 200 > OK or 3/4xx code

Comment: did you solve this issue? i happen to have the same problem

Comment: @Ralph Yeah. Remove the OkHttp3Downloader and it'll work fine.

Comment: @SriramR I finally figured it out, since it's unusual that we can't add a downloader to Picasso. I tried importing the com.squareup.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader rather than com.jakewharton.picasso.OkHttp3Downloader and it works! Thank you btw